# global optimum for non linear sum of squares under constraints

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

i have a global optimisation problem with both equality and inequality constraints for which i am struggling to find a satisfactory solution.

I'm trying to optimise the partition of the overlaps created by combining 3 probabilities P(A), P(B), P(C) to a set of odds ratio objectives.  The overlapping of the 3 probabilities create 7 segments v1 to v7, where v1 to v3 correspond to the solus probabilities (so v1 is P(A solus) etc...), v4 to v6 correspond to the probabilities involving 2 features exactly (so v4 is P((A AND B) NOT C) etc..) and v7 corresponds to all 3 features, ie P(A AND B AND C).

I'm trying to find a solution that would optimise for some target odds ratios for:

- A with {B or C}
- B with {A or C}
- C with {A or B} and
- {1 or 2 features} with {2 or 3 features}

If for example my set of probabilities are P(A)=14%, P(B)=1%, P(C)=8%, and my target odds ratios are {2, 3, 4, 2} then the function i'm trying to minimise is the sum of squares of the differences between my target odds ratios and the odds ratios given by my solution:

```
objective.fc<-function(x){
  f<-rep(NA,4)
  f[1]<-((v4+v6+v7)*(1-(v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7))/(v1*(v2+v3+v5))-2
  f[2]<-((v4+v5+v7)*(1-(v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7))/(v2*(v1+v3+v6))-3
  f[3]<-((v5+v6+v7)*(1-(v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7))/(v3*(v1+v2+v4))-4
  f[4]<-((v4+v5+v6)*(1-(v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7))/(v7*(v1+v2+v3))-2
  f<-drop(t(f)%*%f) # sum of squares
  return(f)
}
```

My equality constraints are:

```
v1+v4+v6+v7=0.14 # P(A)=14%
v2+v4+v5+v7=0.01 # P(B)=1%
v3+v5+v6+v7=0.08 # P(C)=8%
```

And my inequality constraints are that the Vi have to be between 0 and 1 and their sum can't exceed 1.

I've used the function JDEoptim from DEoptimR package but i don't always get convergence. Also, when i do get convergence, i can get different solutions if i run the optimiser more than once, yet if i calculate the objective function with the various solutions, some are clearly better than others...

Is there a way i could solve this analytically rather than rely on an iterative optimiser?

Comment: Note that the Differential Evolution method (used by JDEoptim) is a stochastic method that does not guarantee convergence; no convergence proof exists. Perhaps you problem is ill-suited for this specific method. Possibly you should look into alternative methods, e.g., have a look at the [**nloprt** package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/nloptr.pdf).

Comment: thanks dfri, i have checked nloptr but from what i understand the 2 non-heuristic approaches available are DIRECT and StoGo but neither seem to support the inclusion of equality constraints...  I also tried NlcOptim but get an error message relating to the specification of the bounds which i don't understand...  if anyone knows of a good non-heuristic solver in R that would take both equality and inequality constraints please let me know...

Comment: Each equality constraint can be represented as two inequality constraints, so this is no restriction in these solvers (e.g. equality constraint `Ax = b` is equiv. to inequality constraints `Ax <= b` and `Ax >= b`)

Comment: sorry, my mistake: in StoGo and DIRECT all i see is an option for bounds constraints, so i can't include either my sum of vi <=1 or my equality constraints... do you know a way around this?

Comment: I haven't used neither of them myself. What about the detailed answer given below?

Comment: was hoping to find a native R solution and I can't find an implementation of BARON in R... to use BARON i'd have to use an external API via the package rneos and i'm really struggling to understand how to do this unfortunately. There aren't any relevant example in the rneos reference manual and no tutorial.

Comment: I see. I would still recommend `nloptr` (Specifically `nloptr`, the r interface to `NLopt`, see page 29 in the link above). Also, see Chapter 4 [in this introduction document to `nloptr`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nloptr/vignettes/nloptr.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

This is not such a difficult model to solve. I reformulated slightly (basically replaced a division by a multiplication and substituted out some common expressions) and solved with global solver [BARON](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?=baron):

[image]

My results are

```
---- VAR v  

         LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER

1          .             0.1319         1.0000      
2          .             0.0052         1.0000      
3          .             0.0719         1.0000      
4          .              .             1.0000      
5          .              .             1.0000      
6          .             0.0033         1.0000      
7          .             0.0048         1.0000      

                           LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER

---- VAR w                   .             0.7829         1.0000      

---- VAR f  

         LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER

1        -INF           -1.3769        +INF         
2        -INF            0.5244        +INF         
3        -INF           -3.3572        +INF         
4        -INF            0.5346        +INF         

                           LOWER          LEVEL          UPPER

---- VAR z                 -INF           13.7274        +INF
```

You can try baron [here](http://www.neos-server.org/neos/solvers/go:BARON/GAMS.html) for yourself. I also believe other NLP solvers work ok. I tried a few local NLP solvers such as CONOPT and MINOS and they also gave the same results.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply.  I've yet to manage using BARON in R... but in the meantime i wanted to ask about the method of changing the terms in my sum of squares the way you did it.  Is it ok to do so?  I can see that both ways get to zero at the same solution (ie when achieved odds ratio = target odds ratio) but does the change you implemented work as a cost function, ie when i'm trying to penalise according to how far my achieved odds ratio is from my target odds ratio? Also, does BARON guarantee a global rather than local minimum?

Comment: If I can help it I try to remove divisions in my models (so we don't have "division by zero" in some evaluation). I think I did not make a mistake in reshuffling that equation but if you see an error let me know. You could use the original formulation but then you probably need some non-zero lower bounds on some of the variables to make the division safe. (Actually I tried that formulation also; so I am quite confident in my reformulation).

Answer (score 0):

I reached essentially the same solution as that of BARON using JDEoptim() (see the code below).

```
> fn <- function(v) {
    v1 <- v[1]; v2 <- v[2]; v3 <- v[3]
    v4 <- v[4]; v5 <- v[5]; v6 <- v[6]
    v7 <- v[7]

    w <- 1 - (v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7)

    f <- c( (v4+v6+v7)*w / (v1*(v2+v3+v5)),
            (v4+v5+v7)*w / (v2*(v1+v3+v6)),
            (v5+v6+v7)*w / (v3*(v1+v2+v4)),
            (v4+v5+v6)*w / (v7*(v1+v2+v3)) )

    crossprod(f - c(2, 3, 4, 2))
}
> con <- function(v) {
    v1 <- v[1]; v2 <- v[2]; v3 <- v[3]
    v4 <- v[4]; v5 <- v[5]; v6 <- v[6]
    v7 <- v[7]

    c( v1+v4+v6+v7 - 0.14,
       v2+v4+v5+v7 - 0.01,
       v3+v5+v6+v7 - 0.08 )
}
> soln <- JDEoptim(rep(0, 7), rep(1, 7), fn, con, meq = 3, tol = 1e-7)
> round(soln$par, 4); soln$value
[1] 0.1319 0.0052 0.0719 0.0000 0.0000 0.0033 0.0048
[1] 13.72325
```

Comment: hi Eduardo, thanks for this but i'm afraid it doesn't always work if you change the target odds ratios (ie the c(2,3,4,2) i gave in my example). I've tried many scenarios and many algorithms. At the moment i'm using cobyla, but i'd like to make sure i have a global optimum and i was wondering if i can prove that mathematically. Also with JDEoptim you may get a different solution each time you run it!

Answer (score 0):

Since Differential Evolution (DE) is a stochastic algorithm, it is expected for JDEoptim() to give slightly different answers on each run.
If the problem at hand has many local minima, this means that JDEoptim() may sometimes reach a local one instead of the global minimum for different replicate runs.
A deterministic algorithm such as COBYLA will exhibit the same behavior from separate runs with *different starting guesses*.

For evolutionary algorithms such as DE equality constraints are much harder to deal with than inequality ones. Thus, it might be possible that a reformulation using the equality constraints to explicitly calculate a subset of the original variables (note that the bounds 0 <= v <= 1 for those variables would have to be given explicitly as constraints) would be more robust and easier to handle. This has the added benefit of decreasing the number of decision variables to four instead of seven.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness let me also mention that I tried several randomly generated target odds ratios (`runif(4, 0, 10)`) besides {2, 3, 4, 2}. JDEoptim() found a solution on every case with negligible dispersion among the replicate runs.

I also experimented changing the probabilities P(A), P(B) and P(C) at random (`runif(3)`) with the same findings. (Note that here the inequality constraint `v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6+v7 <= 1` is not necessarily redundant as is the case with the original values.)

Of course, this is only relevant if the generated problem instances are meaningful.